# Get duration length of a raw resource using MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android

I have the following method which is meant to return the duration length (in ms) of a given raw resource.

```
private int getDurationLength(int id) {
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.aboveingredients);
    return mp.getDuration();
}
```

In my raw folder, I have a raw resource called `aboveingredients.m4a` as shown in the image below.

[image: Raw folder with m4a file]

When the following code is executed:

```
audioDuration.setText(getDurationLength(R.raw.aboveingredients));
```

I receive the following error in Logcat:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.aboveingredients)` Although it might be unrelated to your issue, should you be using the `id` that you passed to your `getDurationLength` method?

Comment: Why do you explicitly get the resourse in `getDurationLength` when you pass the `id` as a parameter? EDIT: what Michael said...

Comment: Ignore the variable `id` for now. This was just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setText` expect you to pass in a String not an `integer`

get the `string` value to avoid the error

```
int soundLength = getDurationLength(R.raw.aboveingredients);
audioDuration.setText(String.valueOf(soundLength));
```

or add concatenation to a string

```
 audioDuration.setText("soundLength = " + soundLength);
```